# MySQL min/max for DOUBLE type

Tags: mysql, double

The [MySQL documentation for the DOUBLE type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-overview.html) is really opaque as to what the minimum and maximum values are.

> Permissible values are -1.7976931348623157E+308 to -2.2250738585072014E-308, 0, and 2.2250738585072014E-308 to 1.7976931348623157E+308.

This doesn't make sense to me. Maybe I'm being a mathtard, but I'm not understanding this. There appears to be two possible ranges and zero.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Finding min/max values for double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959411/mysql-finding-min-max-values-for-double)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it has a range of possible positive values, zero, and a range of possible negative values.

The reason they're doing it that way is to ensure you get *both* the maximum and minimum possible numbers on either side of zero.

Alternatively, they could state that the range is `-1.7976931348623157E+308` through `1.7976931348623157E+308` but that doesn't give you any information about the numbers closest to zero that they can represent. (the ones with the `-308` exponent) and you may think you can represent 1E-999 (which you can't).

For the unsigned variant, it just disallows the negative range, which is possibly another reason why they specified the two ranges separately - you can just ignore the negative range totally in that case.

Answer (score 3):

The closest Double to zero is

`2.2250738585072014E-308` ***positive***

`-2.2250738585072014E-308` ***negative***