# MySQL Finding min/max values for double

Tags: mysql, sql, double

[The relevant MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-overview.html) states that for doubles:

> Permissible values are -1.7976931348623157E+308 to -2.2250738585072014E-308, 0, and 2.2250738585072014E-308 to 1.7976931348623157E+308.

and

> These are the theoretical limits, based on the IEEE standard. The actual range might be slightly smaller depending on your hardware or operating system.

I'm finding that the actual range is actually smaller on my system! Is there a SQL query or some other way to find out what the actual minimum and maximum values are for a double?

Comment: What is the actual range on your system?

Comment: @David It'll truncate down to 100000000000000010901051724930857196452234783424494612613028642816.0 for a double(255,0) column. There's got to be a better way to find out the values than setting up a table and attempting to insert absurdly large values to see what it gets truncated to. The documentation also states that a double's maximum storage is 8 bytes. That number is somewhat larger than 64 bits!

Comment: See this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949673/mysql-min-max-for-double-type

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find and prove you know the exact max value on a system, here is a way to do it in a few minutes of execution time.

Do a simple loop that starts with the value of 1 and inserts it.  On each loop multiple the value by 10 until it fails on overflow.  At the end of this you have the minWorkingValue and the maxFailedValue.

Now do a second loop that inserts a value halfway between minWorkingValue and maxFailedValue.  If it succeeds it becomes the new minWorkingValue.  If it fails it becomes the new maxFailedValue.  Continue until maxFailedValue - minWorkingValue = 1.  At the end minWorkingValue is your actual max value you can insert.

As an alternative, if you are pretty sure you know where these values might be, then skip the first step and manually set minWorkingValue and maxFailedValue and straight to the 2nd loop.